# git: Reset to initial state of forked repository

Tags: git, git-reset, git-fork

I forked a repository (which has one `master` branch) in my local namespace.

Ever since, I have several commits on top of `master`, and I also have an additional branch (`test-branch`).

What I want to perform is:

- roll back the `master` branch to the state it was when I forked the repo
- maintain the `test-branch` as is

A potential way of going about this is to checkout `master`, view the log history, find the `sha` of the last commit that was not mine and perform a `git reset <sha_of_last_commit_of_forked_repo>`.

Is there an alternative way?

fyi I have configured two `remotes`: `origin` and `upstream` (the upstream is the repo I forked from, with `push`).

Comment: How about `git reset upstream/master` ?

Comment: thx that did the trick ... didn't want any files either so performed `git reset --hard upstream/master`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I assume however that this brought me to the **current** state of the `upstream/master` (which has in the mean time evolved), not the one it was when forking the repo (which is ok btw, I do not mind)

Comment: It brought you to the state of that branch as it was the last time you fetched from upstream. If you have fetched from upstream after you originally forked the repository then I'm afraid the state of that branch at fork-time is not recorded anywhere. You would have to see if you can find the time of when you forked anywhere and then look at the log to figure out which commit was current at that time but then you're back to your own example, using the sha of a commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do hard reset your local with upstream's master.

```
$ git checkout master

$ git fetch upstream                 # update local upstream history but not merged with working tree
$ git reset --hard upstream/master   # replace local 'master' history = upstream/master history
```

Now, you can create and checkout to a new branch `test-branch` from `master`.

```
$ git checkout -b test-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the upstream has evolved.  You also said that's ok, but just so you're aware of the options:

You can find the last time you integrated changes from upstream into your code - which might be when you initially made the fork (i.e. would be if you haven't merged in additional upstream changes or rebased your work).

```
git merge-base master upstream/master
```

You can then reset to the result of that command

```
git reset --hard `git merge-base master upstream/master`
```

If you *have* rebased your work or merged in additional changes, then it's possible you've gotten to the point where git just isn't keeping track of the "original" state of your fork any more; it's not something git thinks is important, because your fork is just another clone of the upstream as far as git is concerned.

So for future reference, if you create a fork and you think you might sometime later need to refer to "the last upstream commit when I forked", you should tag it.